# Updating Database table from text file not showing correct data

Tags: java, sql, database, eclipse, text-files

When trying to update a database table from eclipse and text file, using my SQL statement does not place the numbers in the correct column. It updates the records but not with the wanted results so I can only presume it is in the parameter for setInt or similar. Any help is appreciated.

```
        String query;
        PreparedStatement statement;


        query = "UPDATE matches SET home_scores_tries = ?, away_scores_tries = ?,  home_penalties = ?, away_penalties = ?, home_conversion = ?, away_conversion = ? WHERE match_id = ?";


        statement = con.prepareStatement(query);

        ArrayList<Scores> listScores = getListScoresFromTextFile("/Users/Ashley/Documents/workspace/Programming Group Project/src/FileUpload/Round_1.txt");

        for(int i = 0; i<listScores.size(); i++){


            statement.setInt(1, listScores.get(i).getHome_scores_tries());
            statement.setInt(2, listScores.get(i).getAway_scores_tries());
            statement.setInt(3, listScores.get(i).getHome_penalties());
            statement.setInt(4, listScores.get(i).getAway_penalties());
            statement.setInt(5, listScores.get(i).getHome_conversion());
            statement.setInt(6, listScores.get(i).getAway_conversion());
            statement.setInt(7, listScores.get(i).getMatch_id());





            statement.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("Insert Success");

        }





    } catch (Exception err) {
        System.out.println(err.getMessage());
    }

}

public static ArrayList<Scores> getListScoresFromTextFile(String filePath) {
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    InputStreamReader isr = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    ArrayList<Scores> listScores = new ArrayList<Scores>();
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(filePath);
        isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
        br = new BufferedReader(isr);

        String line = null;

        String[] strScores = null;

        // loop and get all data from text file

        while (true) {
            line = br.readLine();
            // check line empty, exit loop
            if (line == null) {
                break;
            } else {
                strScores = line.split(",");
                listScores.add(new Scores (Integer.parseInt(strScores[0]),Integer.parseInt(strScores[1]),
                        Integer.parseInt(strScores[2]),Integer.parseInt(strScores[3]),Integer.parseInt(strScores[4]),
                        Integer.parseInt(strScores[5]),Integer.parseInt(strScores[6])));

            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Read File Error");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

        try {
            br.close();
            isr.close();
            fis.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }

    }
    return listScores;

}
}
```

and the txt file was as follows

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,1
1,2,3,4,5,6,2
1,2,3,4,5,6,3  
1,2,3,4,5,6,4
1,2,3,4,5,6,5
1,2,3,4,5,6,6
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
1,2,3,4,5,6,8
1,2,3,4,5,6,9
1,2,3,4,5,6,10
1,2,3,4,5,6,11
1,2,3,4,5,6,12
1,2,3,4,5,6,13
1,2,3,4,5,6,14
1,2,3,4,5,6,15


public class Scores {


private int match_id;
private int home_scores_tries;
private int home_penalties;
private int home_conversion;
private int away_scores_tries;
private int away_penalties;
private int away_conversion;
/**
 * @return the match_id
 */
public int getMatch_id() {
    return match_id;
}
/**
 * @param match_id the match_id to set
 */
public void setMatch_id(int match_id) {
    this.match_id = match_id;
}
/**
 * @return the home_scores_tries
 */
public int getHome_scores_tries() {
    return home_scores_tries;
}
/**
 * @param home_scores_tries the home_scores_tries to set
 */
public void setHome_scores_tries(int home_scores_tries) {
    this.home_scores_tries = home_scores_tries;
}
/**
 * @return the home_penalties
 */
public int getHome_penalties() {
    return home_penalties;
}
/**
 * @param home_penalties the home_penalties to set
 */
public void setHome_penalties(int home_penalties) {
    this.home_penalties = home_penalties;
}
/**
 * @return the home_conversion
 */
public int getHome_conversion() {
    return home_conversion;
}
/**
 * @param home_conversion the home_conversion to set
 */
public void setHome_conversion(int home_conversion) {
    this.home_conversion = home_conversion;
}
/**
 * @return the away_scores_tries
 */
public int getAway_scores_tries() {
    return away_scores_tries;
}
/**
 * @param away_scores_tries the away_scores_tries to set
 */
public void setAway_scores_tries(int away_scores_tries) {
    this.away_scores_tries = away_scores_tries;
}
/**
 * @return the away_penalties
 */
public int getAway_penalties() {
    return away_penalties;
}
/**
 * @param away_penalties the away_penalties to set
 */
public void setAway_penalties(int away_penalties) {
    this.away_penalties = away_penalties;
}
/**
 * @return the away_conversion
 */
public int getAway_conversion() {
    return away_conversion;
}
/**
 * @param away_conversion the away_conversion to set
 */
public void setAway_conversion(int away_conversion) {
    this.away_conversion = away_conversion;
}
public Scores(int match_id, int home_scores_tries, int home_penalties, int home_conversion, int away_scores_tries,
        int away_penalties, int away_conversion) {
    super();
    this.match_id = match_id;
    this.home_scores_tries = home_scores_tries;
    this.home_penalties = home_penalties;
    this.home_conversion = home_conversion;
    this.away_scores_tries = away_scores_tries;
    this.away_penalties = away_penalties;
    this.away_conversion = away_conversion;
}
```

}

[image: This is the result from the database table]

Comment: Can u share the Scores class with its getters and setters?

Comment: Have updated the code to include getters and setters now

Comment: `. It updates the records but not with the wanted results` - so what is happening and what do you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,13
1,2,3,4,5,6,14
1,2,3,4,5,6,15
```

Looks to me like the "match id" is the last column in your data.

```
listScores.add(new Scores (Integer.parseInt(strScores[0]),
    Integer.parseInt(strScores[1]),
    Integer.parseInt(strScores[2]),
    Integer.parseInt(strScores[3]),
    Integer.parseInt(strScores[4]),
    Integer.parseInt(strScores[5]),
    Integer.parseInt(strScores[6])));
```

But you just parse the data and create your `Scores` object in the order the data is parsed.

```
public Scores(int match_id, 
    int home_scores_tries, 
    int home_penalties, 
    int home_conversion, 
    int away_scores_tries, 
    int away_penalties, 
    int away_conversion)
```

Problem is your `Scores` object expects the first value to be the "match id".